# Contact Form - Display items in body of email issues

Tags: php, contact-form

I am having an issue with my contact form and need help with the code.

Here is an image of the "cart", user can add/remove items from the table.
Once they have selected all the products they want, in this example I have added 2 items, they then click the order form button and a form pops up to the left that displays both items.

[image]

My problem is that when the email comes through it only displays the last item and not both items from the form, this is what it looks like in the email

[image]

How do I make it so that it pulls through both items or all items from the form on the left into the body of my email.
Below is my code, if someone can look through and advise what I must change or what I am doing wrong.

```
<section class="order"> 
<?php
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?");
    $sql->bind_param("i", $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    $rows = $result->num_rows; 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
        ?>
        <div class="product-info">
        <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="image" /><br /><br>
        <h3 class="name"><?php echo $row["productname"]; ?></h3><br>
        <h5 class="desc"><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></h5><br>
        <h4 class="code"><?php echo $row["code"]; ?></h4><br>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["productname"]; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_description" value="<?php echo $row["description"]; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_code" value="<?php echo $row["code"]; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="addtocart" value="Add to Cart" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        }
        ?>
    
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
    {
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
        if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
        {
            $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
                'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'item_description'  =>  $_POST["hidden_description"],
                'item_code'         =>  $_POST["hidden_code"],
                'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]);
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
                }
                else
                {
                echo ("<br><br><div class='alert alert-danger'>Item already added.</div>");   
        }
    }
        else
        {
            $item_array = array(
                'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
                'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'item_description'  =>  $_POST["hidden_description"],
                'item_code'         =>  $_POST["hidden_code"],
                'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]);
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}

if(isset($_GET["action"]))
{
    if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
    {
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])
            {
                unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
                echo ("<br><br><div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully Removed Item</div>");

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<br />
<h2>Order Details</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
    <th width="35%">Item Name</th>
    <th width="45%">Description</th>
    <th width="18%">Code</th>
    <th width="2%">Qty</th>
    <th width="5%">Action</th>

    </tr>
<?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_description"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_code"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>
    <td><a href="cart.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"];?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
<td><button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button></td>
</section>
<section>


<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
            <form method="post" action="cart.php">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your e-mail"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Your contact number"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br><br>
            <h2>Order Details</h2>
            
<?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>Item Name:<input type="text" name="productname" value="<?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?>"></td><br>
    <td>Description:<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $values["item_description"]; ?>"></td><br>
    <td>Code:<input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $values["item_code"]; ?>"></td><br>
    <td>Qty:<input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?>"></td><br><br>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

            <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">SEND</button><br>
                
            
            <?php 

                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
                $number = $_POST['number'];
                $product = $_POST['productname'];
                $description = $_POST['description'];
                $code = $_POST['code'];
                $qty = $_POST['qty'];   
                    
                $mailTo = "email@example.co.za";
                $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;

                $txt = "You have received an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n"."Email address: ".$mailFrom.".\n\n"."Contact number: ".$number.".\n\n"."Order Details:\n\n".$product.".\n\n"."Description:".$description.".\n\n"."Product Code:".$code.".\n\n"."Quantity Ordered:".$qty;
    
                mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
                header("Location: cart.php?mailsend");
                }
                ?>
            </form>

</div>
</section>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The fault lies here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $product = $_POST['productname'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];

    $mailTo = "email@example.co.za";
    $headers = "From: " . $mailFrom;

    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " . $name . ".\n\n" . "Email address: " . $mailFrom . ".\n\n" . "Contact number: " . $number . ".\n\n" . "Order Details:\n\n" . $product . ".\n\n" . "Description:" . $description . ".\n\n" . "Product Code:" . $code . ".\n\n" . "Quantity Ordered:" . $qty;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: cart.php?mailsend");
}
```

The `$txt` variable is responsible for the text in the Email and you are setting its value to the last order posted via the form. You have to concatenate every order. So, you have to do something like `$txt .= "You...."` Use the (.) operator to concatenate product details every time

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. Apologies for being such a noob here. Its the first time I am attempting this.

Comment: This is what I did based on your advise.`$txt="You have received an e-mail from ".$name.".\n\n"."Email address: ".$mailFrom.".\n\n"."Contact number: ".$number.".\n\n";
    $txt = " Order Details ".$product.".\n\n"."Description: ".$description.".\n\n"."Code: ".$code.".\n\n";
 $txt .= " Order Details ".$product.".\n\n"."Description: ".$description.".\n\n"."Code: ".$code.".\n\n";`

Comment: The result is that it displays 2 items now, but they are the same item still and not the second one. I know I am doing something wrong here, please advise what I did wrong based on the above code. My output looks like this:  Order Details Gas Passive 5000.

Description: This is product 3.

Code: 9I10J11K12L.

 Order Details Gas Passive 5000.

Description: This is product 3.

Code: 9I10J11K12L.

Comment: As you can see the `$_POST["productname"]` will always return the last product since it is not an array and in the for-each loop you are giving all the items the same name, description, code and quantity hence it will only receive the last given values for those. You could use `name="produtname[]"` instead which will send an array of prouct names so then if you `print_r($_POST["productname"])` it will return array of all product names. Check it once.